# Calling php script with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I've got this simple page to understand the workings of ajax, but I haven't been able to execute the specified php file and get a success.
Here's the code, extra points for explanation:

html page:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="addToDb()">click me!</button>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1./jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/addtodb.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js script:

```
function addToDb()
{
    var source = "SoundCloud";
    var partyKey = "4";
    var id = "0987654321";
    //window.alert("check your db"); // this is called as expected
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        // correctly finds the script but never executes it
        url: 'PHP/functionFilter.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {functionname: 'addSong'},
        success: function(response) { window.alert(response); }
    });
};
```

php file:

```
<?php
echo "".$_POST['functionname'];
?>
```

note I do not get any errors.

Comment: My php code now looks like this. but the intended functionality is still not achieved. I'm still not getting a response:`$anArray;
if (isset($_POST['functionname'])) {
$anArray = array('message' => $_POST['functionname']);

else
$anArray = array('message' => "error");
echo json_encode($anArray);`

Comment: are you sure that  url: 'PHP/functionFilter.php', is correct ?. what do you see in your browser console . is the request getting success ?? what is the status of your request ?

Comment: yep, this is all I get from my browser console: **Importing XUL nodes into a content document is deprecated. This functionality may be removed soon. jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3:0
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.** I tried changing the path and it did report an error then. so I believe it did find the file

Comment: What is your browser ,  check the network tab to see the request .

Comment: Mozilla firefox, the network tab shows Post to the functionFilter.php preceded by a green circle (I assume that it is working fine). just to note, echoing back a fixed value for the variable $anArray actually works. its just when I involve the $_Post['functionname'] nothing works

Comment: try  data: {'functionname': 'addSong'}, instead of  data: {functionname: 'addSong'}, , wrap the functionname with quotes .

Comment: also just to clarify what is your var_dump($_POST['functionname']); value ?

Comment: I'm still not getting a response . and the value is 'addSong'

Comment: it was a syntax error in the isset(), works now. Thank You for your help and vauluable time.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending your data with dataType "json". You will need to encode your data when you echo out.

```
$array = array("success" => true, "message" => "hello world");
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: That is because $_POST itself is an array. Your $_Post variable is just a single value. You need to create an associative array, like I show in my example. I see you did solve it like that in the end.

Answer (score 0):

try this on your php code,

```
<?php 
    echo json_encode(array(isset($_POST['functionname']) ? $_POST['functionname'] : "error" ));
?>
```

Comment: Tried this solution but it echoes 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

The cumulative solution(s) to my problem(s)

```
$anArray;
if (isset($_POST['functionname']))
{$anArray = array('message' => $_POST['functionname']);}
else
{$anArray = array('message' => "error");}
echo json_encode($anArray);
```